# Even if networkx is installed, it still throws a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'networkx'

Tags: python, networkx

I successfully installed `networkx` using `pip install networkx`. I also tested it with Python using command prompt, and it worked.

[image: Picture of running the 'pip install networkx' command and testing it afterwards with cmd]

Now, when I tried importing the module in Python IDLE, it throws the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/hp/Desktop/PROJECTS/osmnx/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import networkx
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'networkx'
```

[image: Here's a picture that shows that I did the import statement correctly and the error.]

Comment: It appears you are using 2 different versions of python. `3.8.3` (has networkx), and `3.7.3` (doesn't). Try specifying a python version with `python-3.7.3 -m pip install networkx`.

Comment: I'll try to upgrade my Python. I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by upgrading my Python from 3.7.3 to 3.8.5. I ran the import statement after that, but it showed the same error. With that, what I did is to run the `pip install networkx` again in the Command Prompt, and it finally worked!

Answer (score 2):

If your script is running using conda environment you can use:
`conda install networkx -y`

So this will install networkx using conda package manager.
It helped for my case: `import networkx` started working.